# TSQL Help Without Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I have below data and the output i need is in Column: **New Inventory**. Currently using Cursor to derive the values but there is performance issue as the no.of record increases in source table.

| ID | Item | Inventory | Projected Shipment | Receipt | LinkDate | NewInventory |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item1 | '10' | '2' | '5' | '01-Sep-2021' | '13' |
| 1 | Item2 | '20' | '3' | '8' | '02-Sep-2021' | '18' |
| 1 | Item3 | '30' | '8' | '15' | '03-Sep-2021' | '25' |
| 2 | Item4 | '40' | '10' | '20' | '01-Sep-2021' | '50' |
| 2 | Item5 | '50' | '25' | '20' | '02-Sep-2021' | '45' |
| 2 | Item6 | '60' | '10' | '20' | '03-Sep-2021' | '55' |

This is how the value is calculated: for each partition based on ID Order by LinkDate the first row will be based on this formula:

```
NewInventory = Inventory+Receipt-ProjectedShipment
```

So the First record becomes : 10+5-3 =13. This value becomes the base inventory and will be used in subsequent rows for calculating the New Invenotry in the same partition.

For Instance 'Item2' for ID=1

```
New Inventory = Previous calculated NewInventory + Current Row Receipt- Current Row Projected Shipment
```

This Becomes

New Inventory = 13 + 8- 3-- This becomes 18

Currently all this logic is implemented with help of Cursor. Please let me know if there is a direct method with tsql only so as to address current performance issue.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you partitioning by `ID` or by `Item`? What does `Item` actually represent?

Comment: `First record becomes : 10+5-3 =13` Where did "3" come from in your first row? And the result of **your** version is 12, not 13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `FIRST_VALUE()` and `SUM()` window functions:

```
SELECT *, 
       FIRST_VALUE(Inventory) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LinkDate) +
       SUM(Receipt - ProjectedShipment) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LinkDate) NewInventory
FROM tablename;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4455999276024ba8796ea1756c2c2bd9).

Comment: Ooh, beat me to the punch with the exact same code. Although I would add `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` in both `OVER`s in case of duplicate dates, it's also more performant

Comment: Thanks! for your help, your logic really worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It works with just SUM() OVER

```
SELECT *, 
       SUM(Inventory + Receipt - ProjectedShipment) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY LinkDate) NewInventory
FROM tablename;
```